# Google Analytics Declaration of GA

Tags: angular, google-analytics

Using Angular 5+

I have tried installing the types for Google Analytics, using npm install @types/google.analytics etc, however that does not work. I get the same error, I also tried adding

```
// Declaration of Google Analytics
declare let ga: any;
```

However, I am still getting the error 
ReferenceError: ga is not defined

My main component

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
});
```

}